# How to hide the bottom bar at ionic view

Tags: ionic-framework

Not sure if this is appearing because recently I had update my node from 6.10.1 to 6.10.2 to run ionic3. But there is a new bottom bar appearing whenever I serve ionic like `ionic serve`

My screen height is too low and I want to hide that thing from by screen.

The bottom bar looks like below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just added a style and it was hidden automatically.

```
#footer { display: none; }
```